# Mostrar un solo valor de un array sin que se repita php

Tags: php, array

yo lo que quiero es poder refrescar la página y que me salga un valor distinto al anterior y después otro, distinto a los dos anteriores, hasta que se muestren todos los almacenados en un array y vuelva a empezar  seleccionar a cualquiera nuevamente
Mi código es este por ahora:

```
<?PHP
     $tecnicos = array('pedro','david','alejandro','jesus','cristian','pablo', 
                       'juan','adam');
     $sorteo = tecnicos;  
     shuffle($sorteo);
     $sorteo = array_chunk($sorteo, 1);
     Echo "<p> Ticket asignado a: </b>.$sorteo[0][0] ;"
?>
```

Comment: Puedes hacerlo almacenando el valor que ya salio en un nuevo array, podrias llamarlo "usados" o algo así,  e ir retirándolo del array anterior "tecnicos" hasta que este ultimo quede vació, si "tecnicos" esta vació le asignarías nuevamente los valores almacenados en "usados".

Comment: Para poder realizar ese proceso necesitas almacenar esa información ya sea en una base de datos o en un Cookie de lo contrario cada vez que refresques el navegador los valores de tus variables también lo harán, o podrías usar AJAX